# Transform "lorem-ipsum" text after login into real content

Tags: jquery, html, web

i have a conceptual/technology question about a "stylish" way of loggin in into a website (showing content).

This is my goal:
The user goes to a website where the whole design is visible, the website is completely loaded, but instead of showing the right text, theres only shown "lorem ipsum"-text. There will be an input field for loggin-in. When the user is succesfully logged in, there will be no redirect, instead the content will be loaded from the server (replaced or faded in with some nice css-animations).

The website will be just static text, no webapp etc.

Now, what would you suggest is the best way to implement this mechanism?
I´m new to serverside programming, my suggestion would be to login via php-script, get the password from a database and then load the content via ajax?

What about "new" technologies like node.js / angular.js?

Thank you so much in advance,
regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use async scripts for loading data dynamically or else you can use php and mysql for loading data from the database, and you can restrict user that if user is log in  into session after user can show specific data or else you can display default suggestion on your web page.

As you say your web site is just static so you have to use JavaScript or async JavaScript  and it is also provided into JQuery so you can also take help of that and that's so easy to understand.